# Select2 - Unable to make Search Term Matches Text Underline

Tags: css, jquery-select2

I am using select2 3.5.2 plugin , Unable to make Search Term Matches Text Underline

Code:

```
.select2-result-selectable .select2-match,
.select2-result-unselectable .select2-match {
    text-decoration: underline !important;
}

   allowClear: true,
  initSelection: function(element, callback) {
                var data = {
                    "id": '1'
                    "text": 'text'
                };
                callback(data);
            },
formatResult: function(item) {
return '<span>' + item.id + '</span></br><span>' + item.text + '</span>';
},
```

this is not working, what may be the reason?

Comment: Are you using a custom formatting function? Are you sure you're using Select2 3.5.2 and not something like 4.0.0-rc.2? Can you include the code you are using to initialize Select2?

Comment: @KevinBrown Yes I am using 3.5.2, I updated my code, if i remove formatResult its works.. but i need format result.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/select2/FhVygJ_21Nk): select2 exports the function( markMatch() ) it uses to do the underlining and it is used in default formatResult function. So you have to do your own markMatch() before you construct html.

I haven't found nice way to do this using select2 library, so I just copied the code from it. Here is my solution:

```
DIACRITICS = {"\u24B6":"A","\uFF21":"A","\u00C0":"A","\u00C1":"A","\u00C2":"A","\u1EA6":"A","\u1EA4":"A","\u1EAA":"A","\u1EA8":"A","\u00C3":"A","\u0100":"A","\u0102":"A","\u1EB0":"A","\u1EAE":"A","\u1EB4":"A","\u1EB2":"A","\u0226":"A","\u01E0":"A","\u00C4":"A","\u01DE":"A","\u1EA2":"A","\u00C5":"A","\u01FA":"A","\u01CD":"A","\u0200":"A","\u0202":"A","\u1EA0":"A","\u1EAC":"A","\u1EB6":"A","\u1E00":"A","\u0104":"A","\u023A":"A","\u2C6F":"A","\uA732":"AA","\u00C6":"AE","\u01FC":"AE","\u01E2":"AE","\uA734":"AO","\uA736":"AU","\uA738":"AV","\uA73A":"AV","\uA73C":"AY","\u24B7":"B","\uFF22":"B","\u1E02":"B","\u1E04":"B","\u1E06":"B","\u0243":"B","\u0182":"B","\u0181":"B","\u24B8":"C","\uFF23":"C","\u0106":"C","\u0108":"C","\u010A":"C","\u010C":"C","\u00C7":"C","\u1E08":"C","\u0187":"C","\u023B":"C","\uA73E":"C","\u24B9":"D","\uFF24":"D","\u1E0A":"D","\u010E":"D","\u1E0C":"D","\u1E10":"D","\u1E12":"D","\u1E0E":"D","\u0110":"D","\u018B":"D","\u018A":"D","\u0189":"D","\uA779":"D","\u01F1":"DZ","\u01C4":"DZ","\u01F2":"Dz","\u01C5":"Dz","\u24BA":"E","\uFF25":"E","\u00C8":"E","\u00C9":"E","\u00CA":"E","\u1EC0":"E","\u1EBE":"E","\u1EC4":"E","\u1EC2":"E","\u1EBC":"E","\u0112":"E","\u1E14":"E","\u1E16":"E","\u0114":"E","\u0116":"E","\u00CB":"E","\u1EBA":"E","\u011A":"E","\u0204":"E","\u0206":"E","\u1EB8":"E","\u1EC6":"E","\u0228":"E","\u1E1C":"E","\u0118":"E","\u1E18":"E","\u1E1A":"E","\u0190":"E","\u018E":"E","\u24BB":"F","\uFF26":"F","\u1E1E":"F","\u0191":"F","\uA77B":"F","\u24BC":"G","\uFF27":"G","\u01F4":"G","\u011C":"G","\u1E20":"G","\u011E":"G","\u0120":"G","\u01E6":"G","\u0122":"G","\u01E4":"G","\u0193":"G","\uA7A0":"G","\uA77D":"G","\uA77E":"G","\u24BD":"H","\uFF28":"H","\u0124":"H","\u1E22":"H","\u1E26":"H","\u021E":"H","\u1E24":"H","\u1E28":"H","\u1E2A":"H","\u0126":"H","\u2C67":"H","\u2C75":"H","\uA78D":"H","\u24BE":"I","\uFF29":"I","\u00CC":"I","\u00CD":"I","\u00CE":"I","\u0128":"I","\u012A":"I","\u012C":"I","\u0130":"I","\u00CF":"I","\u1E2E":"I","\u1EC8":"I","\u01CF":"I","\u0208":"I","\u020A":"I","\u1ECA":"I","\u012E":"I","\u1E2C":"I","\u0197":"I","\u24BF":"J","\uFF2A":"J","\u0134":"J","\u0248":"J","\u24C0":"K","\uFF2B":"K","\u1E30":"K","\u01E8":"K","\u1E32":"K","\u0136":"K","\u1E34":"K","\u0198":"K","\u2C69":"K","\uA740":"K","\uA742":"K","\uA744":"K","\uA7A2":"K","\u24C1":"L","\uFF2C":"L","\u013F":"L","\u0139":"L","\u013D":"L","\u1E36":"L","\u1E38":"L","\u013B":"L","\u1E3C":"L","\u1E3A":"L","\u0141":"L","\u023D":"L","\u2C62":"L","\u2C60":"L","\uA748":"L","\uA746":"L","\uA780":"L","\u01C7":"LJ","\u01C8":"Lj","\u24C2":"M","\uFF2D":"M","\u1E3E":"M","\u1E40":"M","\u1E42":"M","\u2C6E":"M","\u019C":"M","\u24C3":"N","\uFF2E":"N","\u01F8":"N","\u0143":"N","\u00D1":"N","\u1E44":"N","\u0147":"N","\u1E46":"N","\u0145":"N","\u1E4A":"N","\u1E48":"N","\u0220":"N","\u019D":"N","\uA790":"N","\uA7A4":"N","\u01CA":"NJ","\u01CB":"Nj","\u24C4":"O","\uFF2F":"O","\u00D2":"O","\u00D3":"O","\u00D4":"O","\u1ED2":"O","\u1ED0":"O","\u1ED6":"O","\u1ED4":"O","\u00D5":"O","\u1E4C":"O","\u022C":"O","\u1E4E":"O","\u014C":"O","\u1E50":"O","\u1E52":"O","\u014E":"O","\u022E":"O","\u0230":"O","\u00D6":"O","\u022A":"O","\u1ECE":"O","\u0150":"O","\u01D1":"O","\u020C":"O","\u020E":"O","\u01A0":"O","\u1EDC":"O","\u1EDA":"O","\u1EE0":"O","\u1EDE":"O","\u1EE2":"O","\u1ECC":"O","\u1ED8":"O","\u01EA":"O","\u01EC":"O","\u00D8":"O","\u01FE":"O","\u0186":"O","\u019F":"O","\uA74A":"O","\uA74C":"O","\u01A2":"OI","\uA74E":"OO","\u0222":"OU","\u24C5":"P","\uFF30":"P","\u1E54":"P","\u1E56":"P","\u01A4":"P","\u2C63":"P","\uA750":"P","\uA752":"P","\uA754":"P","\u24C6":"Q","\uFF31":"Q","\uA756":"Q","\uA758":"Q","\u024A":"Q","\u24C7":"R","\uFF32":"R","\u0154":"R","\u1E58":"R","\u0158":"R","\u0210":"R","\u0212":"R","\u1E5A":"R","\u1E5C":"R","\u0156":"R","\u1E5E":"R","\u024C":"R","\u2C64":"R","\uA75A":"R","\uA7A6":"R","\uA782":"R","\u24C8":"S","\uFF33":"S","\u1E9E":"S","\u015A":"S","\u1E64":"S","\u015C":"S","\u1E60":"S","\u0160":"S","\u1E66":"S","\u1E62":"S","\u1E68":"S","\u0218":"S","\u015E":"S","\u2C7E":"S","\uA7A8":"S","\uA784":"S","\u24C9":"T","\uFF34":"T","\u1E6A":"T","\u0164":"T","\u1E6C":"T","\u021A":"T","\u0162":"T","\u1E70":"T","\u1E6E":"T","\u0166":"T","\u01AC":"T","\u01AE":"T","\u023E":"T","\uA786":"T","\uA728":"TZ","\u24CA":"U","\uFF35":"U","\u00D9":"U","\u00DA":"U","\u00DB":"U","\u0168":"U","\u1E78":"U","\u016A":"U","\u1E7A":"U","\u016C":"U","\u00DC":"U","\u01DB":"U","\u01D7":"U","\u01D5":"U","\u01D9":"U","\u1EE6":"U","\u016E":"U","\u0170":"U","\u01D3":"U","\u0214":"U","\u0216":"U","\u01AF":"U","\u1EEA":"U","\u1EE8":"U","\u1EEE":"U","\u1EEC":"U","\u1EF0":"U","\u1EE4":"U","\u1E72":"U","\u0172":"U","\u1E76":"U","\u1E74":"U","\u0244":"U","\u24CB":"V","\uFF36":"V","\u1E7C":"V","\u1E7E":"V","\u01B2":"V","\uA75E":"V","\u0245":"V","\uA760":"VY","\u24CC":"W","\uFF37":"W","\u1E80":"W","\u1E82":"W","\u0174":"W","\u1E86":"W","\u1E84":"W","\u1E88":"W","\u2C72":"W","\u24CD":"X","\uFF38":"X","\u1E8A":"X","\u1E8C":"X","\u24CE":"Y","\uFF39":"Y","\u1EF2":"Y","\u00DD":"Y","\u0176":"Y","\u1EF8":"Y","\u0232":"Y","\u1E8E":"Y","\u0178":"Y","\u1EF6":"Y","\u1EF4":"Y","\u01B3":"Y","\u024E":"Y","\u1EFE":"Y","\u24CF":"Z","\uFF3A":"Z","\u0179":"Z","\u1E90":"Z","\u017B":"Z","\u017D":"Z","\u1E92":"Z","\u1E94":"Z","\u01B5":"Z","\u0224":"Z","\u2C7F":"Z","\u2C6B":"Z","\uA762":"Z","\u24D0":"a","\uFF41":"a","\u1E9A":"a","\u00E0":"a","\u00E1":"a","\u00E2":"a","\u1EA7":"a","\u1EA5":"a","\u1EAB":"a","\u1EA9":"a","\u00E3":"a","\u0101":"a","\u0103":"a","\u1EB1":"a","\u1EAF":"a","\u1EB5":"a","\u1EB3":"a","\u0227":"a","\u01E1":"a","\u00E4":"a","\u01DF":"a","\u1EA3":"a","\u00E5":"a","\u01FB":"a","\u01CE":"a","\u0201":"a","\u0203":"a","\u1EA1":"a","\u1EAD":"a","\u1EB7":"a","\u1E01":"a","\u0105":"a","\u2C65":"a","\u0250":"a","\uA733":"aa","\u00E6":"ae","\u01FD":"ae","\u01E3":"ae","\uA735":"ao","\uA737":"au","\uA739":"av","\uA73B":"av","\uA73D":"ay","\u24D1":"b","\uFF42":"b","\u1E03":"b","\u1E05":"b","\u1E07":"b","\u0180":"b","\u0183":"b","\u0253":"b","\u24D2":"c","\uFF43":"c","\u0107":"c","\u0109":"c","\u010B":"c","\u010D":"c","\u00E7":"c","\u1E09":"c","\u0188":"c","\u023C":"c","\uA73F":"c","\u2184":"c","\u24D3":"d","\uFF44":"d","\u1E0B":"d","\u010F":"d","\u1E0D":"d","\u1E11":"d","\u1E13":"d","\u1E0F":"d","\u0111":"d","\u018C":"d","\u0256":"d","\u0257":"d","\uA77A":"d","\u01F3":"dz","\u01C6":"dz","\u24D4":"e","\uFF45":"e","\u00E8":"e","\u00E9":"e","\u00EA":"e","\u1EC1":"e","\u1EBF":"e","\u1EC5":"e","\u1EC3":"e","\u1EBD":"e","\u0113":"e","\u1E15":"e","\u1E17":"e","\u0115":"e","\u0117":"e","\u00EB":"e","\u1EBB":"e","\u011B":"e","\u0205":"e","\u0207":"e","\u1EB9":"e","\u1EC7":"e","\u0229":"e","\u1E1D":"e","\u0119":"e","\u1E19":"e","\u1E1B":"e","\u0247":"e","\u025B":"e","\u01DD":"e","\u24D5":"f","\uFF46":"f","\u1E1F":"f","\u0192":"f","\uA77C":"f","\u24D6":"g","\uFF47":"g","\u01F5":"g","\u011D":"g","\u1E21":"g","\u011F":"g","\u0121":"g","\u01E7":"g","\u0123":"g","\u01E5":"g","\u0260":"g","\uA7A1":"g","\u1D79":"g","\uA77F":"g","\u24D7":"h","\uFF48":"h","\u0125":"h","\u1E23":"h","\u1E27":"h","\u021F":"h","\u1E25":"h","\u1E29":"h","\u1E2B":"h","\u1E96":"h","\u0127":"h","\u2C68":"h","\u2C76":"h","\u0265":"h","\u0195":"hv","\u24D8":"i","\uFF49":"i","\u00EC":"i","\u00ED":"i","\u00EE":"i","\u0129":"i","\u012B":"i","\u012D":"i","\u00EF":"i","\u1E2F":"i","\u1EC9":"i","\u01D0":"i","\u0209":"i","\u020B":"i","\u1ECB":"i","\u012F":"i","\u1E2D":"i","\u0268":"i","\u0131":"i","\u24D9":"j","\uFF4A":"j","\u0135":"j","\u01F0":"j","\u0249":"j","\u24DA":"k","\uFF4B":"k","\u1E31":"k","\u01E9":"k","\u1E33":"k","\u0137":"k","\u1E35":"k","\u0199":"k","\u2C6A":"k","\uA741":"k","\uA743":"k","\uA745":"k","\uA7A3":"k","\u24DB":"l","\uFF4C":"l","\u0140":"l","\u013A":"l","\u013E":"l","\u1E37":"l","\u1E39":"l","\u013C":"l","\u1E3D":"l","\u1E3B":"l","\u017F":"l","\u0142":"l","\u019A":"l","\u026B":"l","\u2C61":"l","\uA749":"l","\uA781":"l","\uA747":"l","\u01C9":"lj","\u24DC":"m","\uFF4D":"m","\u1E3F":"m","\u1E41":"m","\u1E43":"m","\u0271":"m","\u026F":"m","\u24DD":"n","\uFF4E":"n","\u01F9":"n","\u0144":"n","\u00F1":"n","\u1E45":"n","\u0148":"n","\u1E47":"n","\u0146":"n","\u1E4B":"n","\u1E49":"n","\u019E":"n","\u0272":"n","\u0149":"n","\uA791":"n","\uA7A5":"n","\u01CC":"nj","\u24DE":"o","\uFF4F":"o","\u00F2":"o","\u00F3":"o","\u00F4":"o","\u1ED3":"o","\u1ED1":"o","\u1ED7":"o","\u1ED5":"o","\u00F5":"o","\u1E4D":"o","\u022D":"o","\u1E4F":"o","\u014D":"o","\u1E51":"o","\u1E53":"o","\u014F":"o","\u022F":"o","\u0231":"o","\u00F6":"o","\u022B":"o","\u1ECF":"o","\u0151":"o","\u01D2":"o","\u020D":"o","\u020F":"o","\u01A1":"o","\u1EDD":"o","\u1EDB":"o","\u1EE1":"o","\u1EDF":"o","\u1EE3":"o","\u1ECD":"o","\u1ED9":"o","\u01EB":"o","\u01ED":"o","\u00F8":"o","\u01FF":"o","\u0254":"o","\uA74B":"o","\uA74D":"o","\u0275":"o","\u01A3":"oi","\u0223":"ou","\uA74F":"oo","\u24DF":"p","\uFF50":"p","\u1E55":"p","\u1E57":"p","\u01A5":"p","\u1D7D":"p","\uA751":"p","\uA753":"p","\uA755":"p","\u24E0":"q","\uFF51":"q","\u024B":"q","\uA757":"q","\uA759":"q","\u24E1":"r","\uFF52":"r","\u0155":"r","\u1E59":"r","\u0159":"r","\u0211":"r","\u0213":"r","\u1E5B":"r","\u1E5D":"r","\u0157":"r","\u1E5F":"r","\u024D":"r","\u027D":"r","\uA75B":"r","\uA7A7":"r","\uA783":"r","\u24E2":"s","\uFF53":"s","\u00DF":"s","\u015B":"s","\u1E65":"s","\u015D":"s","\u1E61":"s","\u0161":"s","\u1E67":"s","\u1E63":"s","\u1E69":"s","\u0219":"s","\u015F":"s","\u023F":"s","\uA7A9":"s","\uA785":"s","\u1E9B":"s","\u24E3":"t","\uFF54":"t","\u1E6B":"t","\u1E97":"t","\u0165":"t","\u1E6D":"t","\u021B":"t","\u0163":"t","\u1E71":"t","\u1E6F":"t","\u0167":"t","\u01AD":"t","\u0288":"t","\u2C66":"t","\uA787":"t","\uA729":"tz","\u24E4":"u","\uFF55":"u","\u00F9":"u","\u00FA":"u","\u00FB":"u","\u0169":"u","\u1E79":"u","\u016B":"u","\u1E7B":"u","\u016D":"u","\u00FC":"u","\u01DC":"u","\u01D8":"u","\u01D6":"u","\u01DA":"u","\u1EE7":"u","\u016F":"u","\u0171":"u","\u01D4":"u","\u0215":"u","\u0217":"u","\u01B0":"u","\u1EEB":"u","\u1EE9":"u","\u1EEF":"u","\u1EED":"u","\u1EF1":"u","\u1EE5":"u","\u1E73":"u","\u0173":"u","\u1E77":"u","\u1E75":"u","\u0289":"u","\u24E5":"v","\uFF56":"v","\u1E7D":"v","\u1E7F":"v","\u028B":"v","\uA75F":"v","\u028C":"v","\uA761":"vy","\u24E6":"w","\uFF57":"w","\u1E81":"w","\u1E83":"w","\u0175":"w","\u1E87":"w","\u1E85":"w","\u1E98":"w","\u1E89":"w","\u2C73":"w","\u24E7":"x","\uFF58":"x","\u1E8B":"x","\u1E8D":"x","\u24E8":"y","\uFF59":"y","\u1EF3":"y","\u00FD":"y","\u0177":"y","\u1EF9":"y","\u0233":"y","\u1E8F":"y","\u00FF":"y","\u1EF7":"y","\u1E99":"y","\u1EF5":"y","\u01B4":"y","\u024F":"y","\u1EFF":"y","\u24E9":"z","\uFF5A":"z","\u017A":"z","\u1E91":"z","\u017C":"z","\u017E":"z","\u1E93":"z","\u1E95":"z","\u01B6":"z","\u0225":"z","\u0240":"z","\u2C6C":"z","\uA763":"z","\u0386":"\u0391","\u0388":"\u0395","\u0389":"\u0397","\u038A":"\u0399","\u03AA":"\u0399","\u038C":"\u039F","\u038E":"\u03A5","\u03AB":"\u03A5","\u038F":"\u03A9","\u03AC":"\u03B1","\u03AD":"\u03B5","\u03AE":"\u03B7","\u03AF":"\u03B9","\u03CA":"\u03B9","\u0390":"\u03B9","\u03CC":"\u03BF","\u03CD":"\u03C5","\u03CB":"\u03C5","\u03B0":"\u03C5","\u03C9":"\u03C9","\u03C2":"\u03C3"};
function stripDiacritics(str) {
    // Used 'uni range + named function' from http://jsperf.com/diacritics/18
    function match(a) {
        return DIACRITICS[a] || a;
    }

    return str.replace(/[^\u0000-\u007E]/g, match);
};


function markMatch2(text, term, markup, escapeMarkup) {
    var match=stripDiacritics(text.toUpperCase()).indexOf(stripDiacritics(term.toUpperCase())),
        tl=term.length;

    if (match<0) {
        markup.push(escapeMarkup(text));
        return;
    }

    markup.push(escapeMarkup(text.substring(0, match)));
    markup.push(\"<span class='select2-match'>\");
    markup.push(escapeMarkup(text.substring(match, match + tl)));
    markup.push(\"</span>\");
    markup.push(escapeMarkup(text.substring(match + tl, text.length)));
};

function formatResult (item, container, query, escapeMarkup) {
    var text = item.text;

    var markup=[];
    markMatch2(text, query.term, markup, escapeMarkup);
    text = markup.join(\"\");

    if (!item.id) {
      return text;
    }
    var state = $(
      '<span>' + item.id + '</span></br><span>' + text + '</span>'
    );
    return state;
};
```